# How to ask a question but only able to write numbers?

Tags: batch-file

```
set PenaltyLimit = 0

:NewPass
echo Create a penalty limit 
set/p "NewPenaltyLimit=>"
--> if %NewPenaltyLimit%==Numbers?? do (
@echo %NewPenaltyLimit% >> File/PenaltyLimit.txt)
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%W in ("File/PenaltyLimit.txt") do SET PenaltyLimit=%%W
goto lock

:Fail2
@set /a penalty = %penalty% + 1
if %penalty%==%penaltylimit% goto DELETE
goto FAIL
```

What would you put in exchange for the line with the "-->"

Instead of breaking the batch file, writing something random, is it possible that you could somehow either stop someone entirely from writing anything but numbers or make it so the batch file will only read numbers? (Someone what example above this text)

Comment: You could consider running the variable through the `FindStr` command. If you open a Command Prompt window and enter `findstr /?` you can read its usage information. _I might suggest you pay particular attention to a not numeric range_. You might then be able to look at the `If` and `GoTo` commands to create a loop upon a specific condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal

:NewPass
echo Create a password
set/p "newpass=>" || goto :NewPass
:NewPenaltyLimit
cls

echo Create a penalty limit, Numbers only
set /p "NewPenaltyLimit=>" || goto :NewPenaltyLimit
set "NewPenaltyLimit=%NewPenaltyLimit:"=%"
if not defined NewPenaltyLimit goto NewPenaltyLimit
for /f "delims=1234567890" %%A in ("%NewPenaltyLimit%") do goto NewPenaltyLimit

cls
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
echo You chose %NewPenaltyLimit% goto lock
```

If you delimit the value of `%NewPenaltyLimit%` by integers
of `1234567890`, the `do goto :newPass` should only happen
if characters other than integers exist.

Due to possibility of double quotes being input to the `set /p` prompt
which could cause a syntax error when expanded as text when the code
is parsed.
The double quotes will be substituted (*removed*) from the input value
immediately after input. This means that `"86"` will become `86` and
will be accepted as a valid number.

Example values:

- `a1` delimited creates a token with value of `a` which causes
  the `goto :NewPenaltyLimit` to happen.
- `12` delimited creates no token as `1` and `2` are both delimiters.

---

If *Delayed Expansion* is allowed to be enabled.
This version can handle the input without removing double quotes:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:NewPass
echo Create a password
set/p "newpass=>" || goto :NewPass
:NewPenaltyLimit
cls

echo Create a penalty limit, Numbers only
set /p "NewPenaltyLimit=>" || goto :NewPenaltyLimit
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=1234567890" %%A in ("!NewPenaltyLimit!") do (
    endlocal
    goto NewPenaltyLimit
)
endlocal

cls
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
echo You chose %NewPenaltyLimit% goto lock
```

*Delayed Expansion* is only needed for only the `for` loop,
so this may be a better version.

`!NewPenaltyLimit!` is not expanded in the code when the code is parsed,
which means an input such as `"86"` will not cause error and will not be
accepted as a vaild number, as it has double quotes.

---

References:

- View `for /?` for more helpful information.
- View `set /?` for the information about substitution used in this answer.
- View `setlocal /?` and `if /?` about Delayed Expansion.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4f9f9e51adb8c778401df889cef2f5c2                                                                                  Here ill just give you the full code `:NewPass
echo Create a password
set/p "newpass=>"
cls 
echo Create a penalty limit, Numbers only
set /p "NewPenaltyLimit=>" || goto :NewPass
cls
set "NewPenaltyLimit=%NewPenaltyLimit:"=%"
if not defined NewPenaltyLimit goto NewPass
for /f "delims=1234567890" %%A in ("%NewPenaltyLimit%") do goto NewPass
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
echo You chose %NewPenaltyLimit%
goto lock`

Comment: Updated answer based on the minor code differences in your comment. I do not understand the video link which includes "*Could Not Find C:\...*" as nothing in the code can cause that. If that is the full code, then it is probably still a work in progress. Thanks for the information. Please ensure your Question post is updated as needed.

Comment: @ArandomGuy, the error message you've provided in your video link is output from beneath the `:lock` label in your batch file, _(the part where you are hiding the special folder)_. We would need to see that particular section of the file to fix that, but as it would technically be outside of the scope of your question, you should ask a new question if you require help fixing that. In your video, you appear to have used, and the code has accepted, `gg` for the `penalty` input. You're asking Michael questions which are irrelevant to his answer, because you're clearly not working with his code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with embedding a powershell code:

```
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"') do set "number=%%a"
    echo you've entered %number%

endlocal
goto :EOF

: end batch / begin powershell #>

do {
  [Console]::Error.Write("Enter a number:")
  $inputString = read-host
  $value = $inputString -as [Double]
  $ok = $value -ne $NULL
  if ( -not $ok ) {[Console]::Error.WriteLine("You must enter a numeric value") }
}
until ( $ok )

write-host "$value"
```

One advantage is that this can support few types as Integer,Double,Unsigned integer and so on (in this case it is Double.)

You can try also with embedded jscript code (can be used on old XP machines):

```
@if (@X) == (@Y) @end /* JScript comment 
    @echo off 

        for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%~nx0" %* ') do set "number=%%a"
        echo you've entered %number%

    exit /b %errorlevel%       
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */


WScript.StdErr.Write("Enter a number:");
WScript.StdIn.Read(0);
var strMyName = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
var num=parseInt(strMyName);

while(isNaN(num)){
    WScript.StdErr.Write("Enter a number:");
    WScript.StdIn.Read(0);
    var strMyName = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
    var num=parseInt(strMyName);
}

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(num);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't use spaces around `==` comparisions. Your code says `if %NewPenaltyLimit%<space>==<space>Numbers??` which will never match.

Comment: if %NewPenaltyLimit%<space>==<space>Numbers?? I was hoping somebody was able to answer this line, im sorry I didnt make the line have sense in it.

Comment: So remove the spaces around `==`.

Comment: `if 1 == 1 echo match` @Noodles So this should never match? I see `match` echoed. I can insert more spaces, remove spaces on either side of `==` and still matches.

Comment: This "answer" is completely wrong. The `==` compares the token on the left to the token on the right. Any number of token delimiters can lie either side of the `==`. The only restriction is the `=` token delimiter can not appear on the left of `==`, only on the right. For example, `if abc ,; == ,;= abc echo match` results in a match of `abc`.

Comment: I think you are confusing IF rules with SET. It is true that you must not have a space on either side of `=` when doing a SET assignment.